# i am getting an error "Code is unreachable Pylance" what that mean or am i doing any mistake in my code?

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
def percent(marks):
    return (marks[0]+marks[1]+marks[2]+marks[3]/400)*100

    marks1=[54,65,85,54]
    percent1=percent(marks1)

    marks2=[54,52,65,85]
    percent2 = percent(marks2)
    print(percent1,percent2)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The lines after `return` will not be executed anytime. So you can delete them and nothing will change. The message told you about it, because it is very unusual to have such code.

I think you wanted this:

```py
def percent(marks):
    return (marks[0]+marks[1]+marks[2]+marks[3]/400)*100

marks1 = [54, 65, 85, 54]
percent1 = percent(marks1)

marks2 = [54, 52, 65, 85]
percent2 = percent(marks2)
print(percent1, percent2)
```

Spaces in Python code matter. In your code all lines are the part of the function. In fixed code they are not.

Answer (score 16):

For anyone coming across this Stack Overflow question wondering how to disable this feature in which Pylance greys out text which it (often mistakenly) thinks is unreachable, a solution is provided by `luabud` in [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/248#issuecomment-1040722008) and [this comment](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/248#issuecomment-1042121526) on the GitHub issue [How to disable "code is not reachable"...](https://github.com/microsoft/pylance-release/issues/248), which is to place the following entry in your user/workspace `settings.json` file:

```json
    "[python]": {
        "editor.showUnused": false,
    },
```

Comment: FYI: This partially mitigates the problem, since Pylance is still not working properly and marking the code as unreachable.
Full solution in the issues suggested in the official channels is to upgrade selenium, but it didn't help in my personal case.

Answer (score 0):

i know why *code is unreachable* its because the interpreter thinks your program has closed.
Something like *exit()*
what is under *exit()* the code interpreter thinks cannot be executed, But it can be executed!